# I want to execute the code which I have fetched from the server. I can get the code in my console. Want that code to execute on the main browser page

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, google-chrome-extension

So, I have a very basic Google Chrome Extension which has a button in it. I am fetching a script using AJAX from the server in my browser's console. So, when I click on the extension, there is a button and when I click on that button - it will fetch the script from a server and I am able to load that script on the console using console.log

What I want to do is, I want to run that script on my current page.

So my question is - how do I make that script run on my page, which I have loaded in my browser's console?

Here's my basic HTML code for the button -

```
<h4>Click here</h4>

<button class="button button5" id="bt1" >
  <img src="a.png" alt="Click Me" style="height:42px;border:0;">
</button>
```

This is my basic JS code which fetches the script from the server -

```
var buttonClick = document.getElementById('bt1');
buttonClick.addEventListener('click', loadDoc('https://abcd/xyz/pqr/Script1', myFunction));


function loadDoc(url, cFunction) {
  var xhttp;
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var data = this.responseText;
      cFunction(this);



      chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {


      chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: `console.log(${JSON.stringify(data)})`});
      chrome.tabs.getCurrent('data');
      //console.log(taburl);
     });
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

So, basically, I have that script loaded in the "data" variable

So, now, I have to copy that script from the console and paste it in my console so that the script executes and I see the result/output on my current browser page.

So instead of copying and pasting to run it, I want that - when I click on the button in my extension, the script should automatically run/execute on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you'd do this with a chrome extension. However, you could run the javascript using bookmarklet. These act like bookmarks but instead of redirecting, they run code. You can convert your code to a bookmarklet with [this website](https://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/)